# Do not understand a corollary of $N$,$N/M$ are Noetherian submodules of $M$ iff $M$ is noetherian,

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, modules, noetherian

Do not understand a corollary of: "$N$,$N/M$  are  Noetherian submodules of  $M$  iff $M$ is  noetherian"

My professor said as a corollary of the above statement that: "If $R$ is a left Noetherian every finitely generated $R$-module is left Noetherian."

But I can not see why this is a corollary of the above statement, could anyone explain this for me please?

Also could anyone give me a hint for the proof of this corollary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be Noetherian. Then $R^n$ is Noetherian; this is proved by induction. $R^n$ has a submodule $N$ with $N\cong R$ and $R^n/N\cong R^{n-1}$ etc.

If $M$ is finitely generated, then it is isomorphic to a quotient of
some $R^n$, which is Noetherian.

Comment: why N isomorphic to R?

Comment: Take $N=\{(a,0,0,\ldots,0):a\in R\}$.

Comment: My professor said as a hint that it is proved by induction on proper submodules or on number of generators ...... is this related to what you said?

Comment: Induction on number of generators is a slightly different way of doing it.

Comment: should I know the proof of "A module $M$ is Noetherian iff every submodule of $M$ is finitely generated" before making the above proof that u mentioned?